# Spork won't Find RoR Framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, spork

I am learning rails by following the [Rails Tutorial](http://railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) under Ubuntu. I have been using spork and autotest and following the TDD as suggested by the book.

At some point (which I can't tell) the autotest stopped refreshing on it's own and so I killed it, alongside spork to reboot them both (the book does say that happens and that you should reboot them) just like I had done couple of times before.

This time spork won't load and give me this error: "I can't find any testing frameworks to use.  Are you running me from a project directory?" and there doesn't seem to be any documentation whatsoever.

What could it be?

P.S. I am running it from the project directory. I already tried the `bundle install` and `bundle update` commands, I also uninstalled the spork gem with `gem uninstall spork` and reinstalled it with bundler... nothing (Rebooting the computer does nothing as well XD).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using "RSpec" to run the test alongside "autotest". It seems that at some point I accidentally removed the rspec_helper.rb file (or something like that, I can't really recall the name of the file) and that was keeping both "spork" and "autotest" off.

Just had to re-run the generate scripts for RSpec and voilà. All worked like a charm.

P.S.: For sanity run your generate script in a project copy for the the generate script could replace some other files and brake some custom-made functionality.

Comment: By generate script, he means "rails generate rspec:install"